# exception {'Id'} is already being tracked on ChangePasswordAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to update the password in  identity and I've run into the following error:

> The instance of entity type 'TblUsers' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

```
var changePasswordResult = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user: userData, currentPassword: Old, newPassword: New);
```

what am I do to solve this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the exception, `userData` is an instance of your Identity user class that you newed up, but you have previously queried that same user (which has the effect of adding to EF's object cache and change tracking). You're now trying to change the password using the instance that you newed up (which isn't tracked) instead of the instance pulled from the database (which is).

Long and short, if you're going to modify an entity, you should always use an instance pulled from the database to do so, not one you've newed up yourself. If the instance that was pulled from the database is around in this code, then use that. If it isn't, then pull it out of the context again (it will come from the object cache, so no additional query is necessary). Then, use that instance to change the password on.

Comment: This probably is the best answer I found around. But I still don't understand why this situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640075/the-instance-of-entity-type-applicationuser-cannot-be-tracked-because-another falls in that issue, given that I do exactly that - take a new instance from DB and pass it to the userManager function? @chris-pratt